# What does it mean to define events in probability space?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory

Assume for any set $S\subseteq [n]$, there is a parameter $q_S\ge 0$. And these parameters satisfy $\sum_{S\subseteq [n]}q_S=1$.
A claim states that we can define a collection of events $A_1,\dots,A_n$ such that
$$\mathbb{P}\left(\left(\bigcap_{i\in S}A_i\right)\cap \left(\bigcap_{j\in [n]\setminus S} A_j^c\right)\right)=q_S$$
for every $S\subseteq [n]$.

My question is,
(a) what is the definition of "define a collection of events"? How do we know it is well-defined? 
(b) Why there exists such a collection of events of this form satisfying $\mathbb{P}\left(\left(\bigcap_{i\in S}A_i\right)\cap \left(\bigcap_{j\in [n]\setminus S} A_j^c\right)\right)=q_S$? Is there any quantitative relation $q_S$ should satisfy?

Comment: $q_S$ is a probability measure on $2^{[n]}$, the set of subsets of $[n]$. An event in this space is a subset of $2^{[n]}$. "Define a collection of events" just asks you to show that there exist events $A_1,\dots,A_n$ which satisfy that equation.

Comment: But should we know $q_S$ satisfies if $S_1\cap S_2=\emptyset$, then $q_{S_1\cup S_2}=q_{S_1}+q_{S_2}$, to make it a probability measure?

Comment: I think they want you to define the probabilities of the events, as well the events themselves.

Comment: Given any function $p:X\to \mathbb R^+$, where $X$ is finite and $\sum_{x\in X}p(x)=1$, then there is an induced probability measure $\mathbb P$ defined on $X$, where for any $A\subset X$, $\mathbb P(A)=\sum_{a\in A}p(a)$. This new function $\mathbb P$ satisfies $\mathbb P(A\cup B)=\mathbb P(A)+\mathbb P(B)$ when $A,B$ are disjoint. In this case, $X=2^{[n]}$ and $p=q$. There is no requirement on $q$ to satisfy $q_{S_1\cup S_2}=q_{S_1}+q_{S_2}$. Only the induced probability measure $\mathbb P(A) = \sum_{S\in A}q_S$ must satisfy this, and it does, as it always will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple (and minimal) way to construct such a probability space is to choose $\Omega=\{0,1\}^n$, $\mathcal F=2^\Omega$, and $P(\{\omega_S\})=q_S$ for every $S\subseteq[n]$, where each $\omega_S$ is defined as $\omega_S=(\omega^S_k)_{1\leqslant k\leqslant n}$ with $\omega^S_k=\mathbf 1_{k\in S}$.

Thus, $\Omega=\{\omega_S\mid S\subseteq[n]\}$ and the only relevant condition on some family of real numbers $(q_S)$ for this space $(\Omega,\mathcal F,P)$ to define a bona fide probability space, is that every $q_S$ should be nonnegative and that $\sum\limits_{S\subseteq[n]}q_S=1$.

Then, the events $A_k$ are simply $A_k=\{\omega_S\mid S\ni k\}$ and, for every $S\subseteq[n]$, $$\left(\bigcap_{k\in S}A_k\right)\cap \left(\bigcap_{k\in [n]\setminus S} A_k^c\right)=\{\omega_S\}$$